# Combining some() and startsWith() javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array with strings: `const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']`

I am trying to write a function that returns true or false depending on if a string starts with any string in the array, which would be true for example `'Applepie'` or `'Bananabread'`.

I found `startsWith()` and `some()`, and combining them is sort of what I am after.

How would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Seems like you already know which functions to use. Where are you stuck?

Comment: `startsWith` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd call `some` on the array and return the result of `theString.startsWith(theArrayEntryForEachLoopIteration)`, like this:

```
const theString = "Applepie";
const result = fruits.some(fruit => theString.startsWith(fruit));
```

`result` will be `true` if there was a match (your callback returned a truthy value), `false` if there wasn't (your callback never returned a truthy value). `some` will also stop looking the first time your callback returns a truthy value, since there's no point in looking further.

Live Example:

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'];

// Example where it's there:
const theString = "Applepie";
const result = fruits.some(fruit => theString.startsWith(fruit));
console.log(result);

// Example where it isn't
const theString2 = "Toffeepie";
const result2 = fruits.some(fruit => theString2.startsWith(fruit));
console.log(result2);
```

MDN has good reference and tutorial content: [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

Answer (score 1):

```js
  const text = 'Applepie'; //Input Text
  const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'];
  console.log(fruits.some(v => text.startsWith(v)));
```